# How do I create a powershell script for windows that runs 2 python scripts

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, command-prompt

This is the first time I tried doing a shell script.

So this is what I got for now:

```
$pdf = read-host "enter the pdf name"

cmd /k C:\the path\\./PDF_ID.py  $pdf /all> C:\the path\data.txt 

C:\the path\pdf.py
```

So the first python script is executed and it saves the output to the data.txt but I dont know how to run the second python script that analyzes data.txt and outputs if the pdf file contains malware or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run Python from Powershell, then `python <scriptName>.py` will get your job done.

You can give the full path of the Python executable within the command line (incase not working). You could check and ensure that your *python executable path* is available in your system variables.

If you are not looking from any concurrent solution, then directly put these two inside your *samplePS1* file:

```
python firstscript.py ;
python secondscript.py  ;
```

Note: If you want to pass arguments , then you can pass the arguments also. This is a sequential execution.

Hope it helps you.